# Oracle SQL help: after using group by, count types

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I am having a problem I haven't been able to solve.
I have a table with the following columns:
`Personid`, `type`.

There can be several rows for each `personid`
My desired outcome would be an aggregation of how many rows of type 5,12,71 each person has.

So the table will look like this:

```
  Personid  type 5  type 12  type 71

   11          0       2        7
   15          1       6        0
```

Comment: will u please post the query

Comment: My last try was: select personid, count(type) over partition by type).    That one dident give me what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  personid,
  count(case when type = 5 then 1 end) type5cnt,
  count(case when type = 12 then 12 end) type12cnt,
  count(case when type = 71 then 71 end) type71cnt
from table_name
group by personid
```

Comment: Yes!, this worked perfectly. I dident know you can do that. Thank you!